# Username Password Button

Tags: html, css

I'm working on HTML and I'm trying to introduce a box in the middle of the page with two text buttons to insert username and password. I find the way to create the box with the text inside, like the one that disappear when you click on it. How can I do it? Thanks for all! [image]

I was able to create the button and the onClick option for the Tune In but I don't know how to do the two text buttons

Comment: this is the `placeholder` attribute in the `input` tag.

Comment: @njzk2: You mean `placeholder`.

Comment: @SLaks: yes, thanks, confused with android xml attribute

Comment: yep it's the placeholder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
    input[placeholder] {
      font-size: 20px;
      text-align: center;
      }
```

```html
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username"></p>
<input type="text" name="password" placeholder="password"></p>
```

**EDIT**

To increase the placeholder's font size and center the text:

```
input[placeholder] {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  }
```

Comment: ok that's a good way but I don't understand how to create these specified buttons. The size looks fixed

Comment: What do you mean with "how to create these _buttons_"?

Comment: As you can see in the image the placeholders are bigger than the default size. I don't know how to do it

Comment: I've updated my answer with what you need

Comment: Ok. perfect. The problem is that I don't understand how to center the placeholders (centered in the page)

Comment: There you go, check my edit again. You can apply the styles you want to the placeholder

Comment: It does not work. Basically I create the box with the border and the two placeholder but they are moved on the left side of the page

Comment: As you can see with my code, it is working. See it in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7f1jtLzs/) too. Create yourself a fiddle or show us your code so we can see what's causing the issue

Comment: @chiapa - seems like the user would like us to code the page for him. All of the above followups can be easily found via google or a even here

Comment: Thanks Quantico. But I was not able to find this thinks online. As I said I was able to do the placeholder (I call it button and I was wrong) but I wan not able to change the design

Comment: I don't want to, but I'm starting to think like you @Quantico, these aren't hard challenges and are a small research away from anyone. Or, his knowledge on HTML/CSS is very limited and we must respect that too, no one knows everything

Comment: Ok, that's the link. I don't know if it's right because I never used the site http://jsfiddle.net/7f1jtLzs/

Comment: @chiapa I started yesterday working on HTML/CSS

Comment: Once you create a fiddle you must save it and then use the url to show us what you've done. Fiddle, by the way, is a good friend of HTML/CSS developers

Comment: Yeah I did it. I put the code on it but I have a problem with CSS. It says "For CSS use the panel on the right" where I put my CSS

Comment: Well, if it says "Use the panel on the right" I think you should use the panel on the right for CSS. Copy your CSS code and paste it on **the panel on the right**

Comment: Ok. I did it to myself. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, use the placeholder attribute

```
  <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
```

For the password you can also add a password type to prevent the plain text from appearing

```
   <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password>
```

So

```html
<form action="#" style="text-align:center">
     <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"><br>
     <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password">
     <div class="button">
         <button type="submit">Tune In</button>
     </div>
</form>
```

The above code is now centered per your request. You can put the styling in CSS as well

Comment: Use CSS/bootstrap/whatever to get the style you'd like

Answer (score 1):

That's not a `button` but instead an `input`. You can insert them inside your form like this:

```html
<form action="#">
     <input type="text" placeholder="Username" />
     <input type="text" placeholder="Password" />
</form>
```

Comment: Yeah sorry for the word but I don't understand why I have default size of buttons

Comment: You can style it according to your preferences by assigning it an ID.

Comment: I put it in a content. Should I work on it? Another thing. How can I center the buttons?

Comment: Can you please update your main question with the HTML/CSS which you're using? It will be more easier to help you then.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it will work

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter User Name">
```

and I think you should make your password text box of password type as follows

```
   <input type="password" placeholder="Enter password">
```

Comment: No problem.. but again, sadly many people still use ie8 with windows xp. My clients always demands at least funcionality on old browsers and if you have an empty input with no label they won't know what is it for. http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-placeholder

Answer (score 0):

or another aproach if you want to include a little jquery so it will be old browsers compatible.

html:

```
<form action="#">
     <input type="text" class="txtInside" defaultval="user" >
     <input type="text" class="txtInside" defaultval="pass" >
</form>
```

jquery:

```
$('body').ready(function () {
            $('.txtInside').each(function () {
                $(this).val($(this).attr('defaultVal'));
                $(this).css({ color: '#999999' });
            });

            $('.txtInside').focus(function () {
                if ($(this).val() == $(this).attr('defaultVal')) {
                    $(this).val('');
                    $(this).css({ color: '#000' });
                }
            });
            $('.txtInside').blur(function () {
                if ($(this).val() == '') {
                    $(this).val($(this).attr('defaultVal'));
                    $(this).css({ color: '#999999' });
                }
            });
        });
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/fhs43ke8/

In thsi case you write the test you want in "defaultval". the script include a change of text color in case you want it

Comment: Thanks but I use the HTML/CSS not the JavaScript